# Possible to attach screenshot to SpecRun test report

Tags: specflow, specrun

I'm looking into SpecFlow and SpecRun considering changing away from our MbUnit setup. But i ran into a road block, how do I attach a screenshot to a SpecRun report?

Or alternativly customize the test report to contain a clickable url?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512918/insert-screenshots-in-specrun-specflow-test-execution-reports (duplicate?)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom report and specify it while running SpecRun.